# Access review item from question with pending votes

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-close

When I see a question that has pending close votes (or reopen votes), I can cast yet another vote to close (reopen) it but cannot cast a vote to keep it open (closed).

The only way to do that now is [find the corresponding review item with Data.SE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/542689/find-reviews-on-post) and go to its URL manually.

Since I can do this already and can't see or think of any valid reason for this discrepancy, there's no reason to keep it unavailable in the stock UI.

Comment: Or you can use the userscript in [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306412/578411) of mine.

Comment: @rene only works with 10k+ though right?

Comment: (Not saying it isn't awesome, just worth mentioning... and OP is < 10k)

Comment: Ah, yes that is true @Cai, I keep forgetting that ...

Comment: @rene "He that is warm thinks all so" of something like that ;-)